# Is the third season of Game of Thrones (now following A Storm of Swords) going to have a second part?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

As the end to the third season slowly approaches, it looks like many of the third book’s (A Storm of Swords) events are going to be postponed to another season or entirely dropped like so many things were dropped from the previous two seasons in comparison to the previous two books.

There are only two episodes left (9 and 10). How are they going to fit in the rest of the book? Is the third season going to be concluded with

> The Red Wedding, or even both weddings at the same time (kings wedding), Jon’s escape, and the attack on the Wall?

They don’t really have time for anything else at this pace. The last episode ended with

> Sansa’s wedding and Sam’s encounter with the wights in the village (he hasn’t even met Coldhands yet)

How are they going to fit the rest of the events?

> What about Bran and Daenerys?

Is there a rumor, a comment or really anything that would confirm that the events from the third book are going to be done in two parts - season 3 and season 4; like some of the new editions of the third book?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a well publicized fact that the third season consists of the first half of the third book, and that the second half will be coming in season 4. In fact, the best quote seems to be the one from the Huffington Post, don't expect there to be a 1 to 1 book to season ratio, they are trying to keep the sagas together. I wouldn't be surprised at all if book 4/5 are combined together into a 2-3 season arc, for instance. Here's some references, and the Huffington Post quote.

http://www.tvguide.com/News/Game-Thrones-End-Seven-Seasons-1065889.aspx
http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2012/04/11/game-of-thrones-third-season_n_1416386.html

> As I said in my conversation with Weiss, it sounds as though the way
>   to look at upcoming season (hopefully seasons) of the show are as
>   portions of the overall saga, not sections of particular books.
>
> "Yeah," Weiss said. "A season of television needs to feel like a
>   season of television. We have so many storylines to juggle, and they
>   all need to ideally have a sense of a beginning, middle and end over
>   the course of a season. Each character needs to feel like they're
>   traveling a specific road in the course of a season, and coming out as
>   a different person than they went in. It's never going to be about
>   taking a book and ripping it in half -- 'At page 673, this is the
>   place where [the season] ends.' It comes down to case-by-case
>   [decisions] with each story and how best to serve each character's
>   story going forward."

Comment: Oh, very nice. There is even a speculation about the future season being a combination of books 4 and 5. :D

Comment: @Secko more show is better than less in the case of Game of Thrones.  I hope they don't strip down too much from the books even if that means a single book covering 2-3 seasons of the show.

Comment: @Mkalafut Good point on "more show is better then less". I got to be frank about my intentions with this question. First, I'm just killing time until The Winds of Winter "arrive". Second, I'm wondering if The Winds of Winter will come out before they finish events of A Dance With Dragons in the series (whichever season).